# Does only one Python interpreter execute multiple concurrent scripts?

Tags: python, linux, rest, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a Python script that sends 4GB worth of data to a server in 10MB chunks using REST API.  No matter how many of these scripts I invoke concurrently, I get exactly the same overall throughput client-side (10Gb network, server class system):

1 invocation = 300MB/s

2 invocations = 300MB/s

4 invocations = 300MB/s

8 invocations = 300MB/s

At first I though it was some kind of disk read limitation, but I modified the script so that it does not require hard drive access and uses minimal memory and I still get the exact same throughput.  CPU and memory usage during execution is minimal.

Researching further, I read that the Python interpreter is single threaded.  That is fine (and makes sense I guess), but is it possible that only one instance of the Python interpreter is invoked at a time, despite multiple Python scripts being invoked concurrently?

Comment: Are you using AWS or similar architecture? Or something else?

Comment: Can you send more than 300MB/s using other methods?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is something similar to AWS.

Comment: To exclude the possibility of saturation that Andrew mentioned in his answer, if you deliberately cripple your script to be slower (like adding pauses), does throughput go up with more instances?

Comment: The Python interpreter threading is implementation specific.  While CPython may only have one thread executing the interpreter, the actual I/O generally runs outside of the interpreter, allowing for concurrent I/O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, multiple python processes executed separately will not share threads or any other state.

The most likely case is that 300MB/s is either the fastest your client can support, or the fastest your server can support.

300MB/s is extremely fast, so much so that I wonder if you haven't confused megabytes with megabits.

Comment: It is fast, but it is also a 10Gb network, so 300MB/s is only 1/3 of the link.  My goal is to hit link speed.  I can pretty much guarantee that the server can support more.  What could be limiting me on the client?  I believe I have designed the script to be as lightweight as possible.  CPU utilization is never more than 5%.  It has 64GB of RAM, but never uses more than a couple gigabytes.  It is probably not delayed ACKs because I think my throughput would still improve going from 1 thread to 2 threads.

Comment: Is there any chance there is congestion at the network hardware level, in-between your client and the server?

Comment: Actually, yes.  It is very possible.  I will have to double check to see how many switches I am going through from the client to the server, but it is at least one.  I should try connecting the client directly to the switch, and perhaps isolating it completely from the other switches that are connected to it, to see what happens.  I will report back.  And to further prove that the server is not the issue, I should run the script from multiple clients.

Comment: It was not a network congestion issue.  My server does not seem to like chunk encodings for some reason.  Oh well.